# If $A$ is a nonempty subset of $\mathbb{R}$, which of the four properties of a dedekind cut does $\bigcap A$ have?

Tags: elementary-set-theory

For some reason I'm having a hard time conceptualizing what $\bigcap A$ would look like if $A$ is a subset of $\mathbb{R}$.

For reference, the properties of a dedekind cut that I am working with are:

$A$ is a subset of $\mathbb{Q}$ such that 1. $p <_\mathbb{Q} q$ and $q \in A$ imply $p \in A$, 2. $A$ has no greatest element, 3. $A \neq \emptyset$, and 4. $A \neq \mathbb{Q}$.

Any help would be greatly appreciated!

Comment: Is $A$ a set, or a family of sets? If not a family, what does $\cap A$ mean?

Comment: Presumably real numbers are being identified with cuts here.  As a start, think about what happens if $A$ is a set consisting of two real numbers.

Comment: @Joe They seem to be working with the Dedekind cut definition of $\mathbb{R}$, so $A$ being a subset of $\mathbb{R}$ implies it is a set of subsets of $\mathbb{Q}$.

Comment: @NateEldredge so $\bigcap A$ would be the smallest element in $A$?